# Prove the inequality: $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{2+\arctan x} dx \geq \ln 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, inequality

I have started taking **calculus 2** class without any specific knowledge of calculus 1. Our current topic is concerning **definite integral**. Could you please help to explain how I can evaluate the following inequality, also suggest which topics do I have to learn in order to catch up with indefinite integral.

$$\int_0^2 \frac{1}{2+\arctan x} dx \geq \ln 2$$

Comment: Can you compare $\arctan(x)$ to $x$?  On the interval $(0,2)$ which is bigger?  Is $\arctan(x)$ always bigger or is $x$ always bigger or do they some times change which is bigger over that interval?  Then using this knowledge, which is bigger over that interval?  $\frac{1}{2+\arctan(x)}$ or $\frac{1}{2+x}$?  Can you evaluate $\int\limits_0^2\frac{1}{2+x}dx$ and use that result to compare to $\int\limits_0^2\frac{1}{2+\arctan(x)}dx$?

Comment: Yes, I think that will work. Thanks!

Comment: @FriendlyFred, please, specify your titles in future. It is too general.

Comment: Okay, this is the first question I am posting, so will be more specific in the future)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, I hope you stay around and contribute to the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two important things to remember to start with here:

- $\arctan(0)=0$
- The derivative of $\arctan(x)$ with respect to $x$ is $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ (*Something you will have learned from differential calculus*) which we can notice that for all values of $x$ is a positive number strictly less than $1$ with the exception of when $x=0$ where it is identically equal to $1$.

These two facts together along with noting the derivative of $f(x)=x$ is identically equal to $1$ show that on the interval $(0,2)$ you have that $x$ is always strictly larger than $\arctan(x)$

Using this, we find that on the interval $(0,2)$ we have that $\frac{1}{2+\arctan(x)}$ is always strictly larger than $\frac{1}{2+x}$ (*since we are dividing by a smaller amount*) from which it follows that $\int_0^2 \frac{1}{2+\arctan(x)}dx \geq \int_0^2\frac{1}{2+x}dx$

Finally, correctly evaluating the integral on the right yields the value of $\ln(2)$ which when replaced in the inequality completes the proof.

Comment: Yes, of course! It's the best way here. +1

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

As $\arctan x<x$,

$$\frac1{2+\arctan x}>\frac1{2+x}$$

and

$$\int_0^2\frac1{2+\arctan x}>\int_0^2\frac1{2+x}=\log 2.$$

---

If need be, the first inequality can be established as follows:

$$\frac1{1+t^2}<1$$ and

$$\int_0^x\frac1{1+t^2}\,dt<\int_0^x dt.$$

Comment: Thank you it really helped!